# Accessing properties of composited classes without breaking encapsulation

Tags: object-oriented, ecmascript

We've built a class that allows you to easily draw stuff on a `<canvas>` element.

That class is called `Canvas`. I've encapsulated the `<canvas>` element and the class itself in a WebComponent, called `<paper-canvas>`.

```
<paper-canvas>
  <canvas id="#canvas"></canvas>
<paper-canvas>

<script>
  class PaperCanvas {
    constructor() {
      this.canvas = new Canvas('#canvas')
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `Canvas` class has a lot of methods such as:

- `importPNG()`
- `drawSquare()`

etc..

So right now when we want to say `importPNG()` we do something like this:

`document.querySelector('paper-canvas').canvas.importPNG()`

but I get a feeling that this is breaking encapsulation since I'm accessing internal properties of `<paper-canvas>`.

An alternative would be to do something like this:

```
<paper-canvas>
  <canvas id="#canvas"></canvas>
<paper-canvas>

<script>
  class PaperCanvas {
    constructor() {
      this.canvas = new Canvas('#canvas')
    }

    importPNG() {
      return this.canvas.importPNG()
    }
  }
</script>
```

and then for using it:

`document.querySelector('paper-canvas').importPNG()`

but this means that every time I add a new method on `Canvas` that should be publicly accessible to other members, I would *also* need to add it to my `PaperCanvas` class.

What's the recommended way of dealing with such cases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Law of Demeter and its applicability](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316678/law-of-demeter-and-its-applicability)

Comment: This is why inheritance of classes includes automatic delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you really want is to inherit `PaperCanvas` from `Canvas`. ECMAScript6 (which is, I guess, the language you are using here) supports this, you may implement it like

```
class PaperCanvas extends Canvas {
    constructor() {
        super('#canvas');
    }
}
```

Now a call like

```
 document.querySelector('paper-canvas').importPNG()
```

should work, with no need to implement delegation calls for every inherited method.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What are delegation calls? Duplicate methods from `Canvas` to `PaperCanvas`, i.e adding `PaperCanvas.importPNG` that would just call `this.canvas.importPNG`?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: yep, what else?